# How to get JQuery Mobile/ JQuery UI Styling to carry through mustache templating

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile

I want to create a JQuery Mobile list with the associated styling. I have this working without templating. However when I try to create the same list in a Mustache template, the styling does not carry through when the template is rendered. How can I fix this?

Here is what it looks like:
[image]

I want it to look like the bottom list, but rendered through the Mustache template.

Here is all the code for the page:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>

<!-- Include Mustache Templating -->
      <script src="JSfiles/mustache.min.js"></script>

      <script>
        $(function(){
          var contentTemplate = $("#template").html();
          Mustache.parse(contentTemplate);
          var renderedContent = Mustache.render(contentTemplate);
          $("#content").html(renderedContent);
        })
      </script>

</head>
<body>

<div data-role="page" id="pageone">

  <div id="content" data-role="main" class="ui-content"></div>

  <div data-role="main" class="ui-content">
    <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true">
      <li>
        <a href="#"><img src="chrome.png"></a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#"><img src="firefox.png"></a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div> 

</body>
</html>


<script id="template" type="x-tmpl-mustache">
  <div>
  <h2>List With Thumbnails:</h2>
    <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true">
      <li>
        <a href="#"><img src="chrome.png"></a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#"><img src="firefox.png"></a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    </div>
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your list is not there when the page renders, you need to tell jQM to enhance the widget:

```
$("#content").html(renderedContent).enhanceWithin();
```

or

```
$("#content").html(renderedContent).find("ul").listview();
```